# $f$ holomorphic on $\Delta$ the open unitary disk $\Rightarrow\lim_{z\to\partial\Delta}$ exists finite in $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\Delta\to\Bbb C$ holomorphic, where $\Delta=\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;|z|<1\}$ is the open unitary disk.

How can I prove that $\lim_{z\to z_0}$ exists finite in $\Bbb C,\;\;\;\forall z_0\in\partial\Delta$?

Any hint/counterexamples (however I think it's right)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the classic counterexamples is $(1-z)^{-1}$. If that's not bad enough for you, look at
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Regard this simple counterexample:

f(z)= 1/(z-1) is holomorphic in the open unitdisc, but f(z) does not exist when z approaches 1.